# sql server udf, return the same type as the input expression

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, decimal, user-defined-functions

is it possible for a udf to return the same data type as one of its parameters?

i would like my udf to accept a decimal of any precision and scale
and return the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function accept and return a [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx).

Comment: i need to use the round function so i need a decimal

Comment: You can use SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(colA,'Precision') to retrieve the precision of the variant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx  Then you can use a CASE statement to treat cast different variants in a different way.